# Checking if two strings are permutations of each other in Python

Tags: algorithm, python

I'm checking if two strings `a` and `b` are permutations of each other, and I'm wondering what the ideal way to do this is in Python. From the Zen of Python, "There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it," but I see there are at least two ways:

```
sorted(a) == sorted(b)
```

and

```
all(a.count(char) == b.count(char) for char in a)
```

but the first one is slower when (for example) the first char of `a` is nowhere in `b`, and the second is slower when they are actually permutations.

Is there any better (either in the sense of more Pythonic, or in the sense of faster on average) way to do it? Or should I just choose from these two depending on which situation I expect to be most common?

Comment: i don't think that quote is not meant to be applied to algorithms, but how many ways there are to implement one specific algorithm.

Comment: Hop is right.  The rule applies to the python command set, not your actual code.  For example, there are several libraries that do similar math routines.

Comment: Second way is broken, eg for `a="cat"` and `b="pact"`

Comment: Like @gnibbler pointed out, the second option is incorrect because you're only iterating over the characters of one string and comparing the frequency of those characters. There may be characters in the other string that you're not counting. You can compare the length first and continue if it's equal, or a better alternative IMO is to use a dictionary where the keys are the characters and the values are the character's frequency.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

heuristically you're probably better to split them off based on string size.

Pseudocode:

```
returnvalue = false
if len(a) == len(b)
   if len(a) < threshold
      returnvalue = (sorted(a) == sorted(b))
   else
       returnvalue = naminsmethod(a, b)
return returnvalue
```

If performance is critical, and string size can be large or small then this is what I'd do.

It's pretty common to split things like this based on input size or type. Algorithms have different strengths or weaknesses and it would be foolish to use one where another would be better... In this case Namin's method is O(n), but has a larger constant factor than the O(n log n) sorted method.

Comment: Good plan, in my tests Namin's method becomes faster for string lengths over 1 million. All my strings are shorter than that, so I will use sorted for now and keep Namin's in mind.

Comment: Instead of setting returnvalue, just return.

Comment: The _worst case_ for timsort is O(n*log(n)). Whereever  you have partially sorted "runs" the performance is better. Since you can't have a million different _bytes_, the performance should be somewhat better than O(n*log(n)). For Python3 where strings are unicode the the situation isn't quite as good, but for long enough strings you should still see a reduction in the number of comparisions.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a way which is O(n), asymptotically better than the two ways you suggest.

```
import collections

def same_permutation(a, b):
    d = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for x in a:
        d[x] += 1
    for x in b:
        d[x] -= 1
    return not any(d.itervalues())

## same_permutation([1,2,3],[2,3,1])
#. True

## same_permutation([1,2,3],[2,3,1,1])
#. False
```

Comment: for Python 3.0, replace .itervalues() with just .values()

Comment: This is significantly longer and more complex than necessary and turns out to be slower in every case I tested than the simple "sorted" solution.  I can't find anything "better" about it.

Comment: I was going to ask HAVE YOU MEASURED??  Thanks, Robert.

Comment: Actually, when you run it against 20,000,000 characters, namin's version is 50% faster. So if you're looking for permutations in Finnish, it might be worth a look :)

Comment: As namin said, it is asymptotically better - and you do not need to measure, just to demonstrate that it is O(n) against O(n log(n)).

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm, my strings are actually not long enough that it is faster, but I will remember it for the future. 

Am I right that you can express this using collections.defaultdict(int)? I modified it to use this and it was marginally faster.

Comment: The last 4 lines can be replaced with "return not any(d.itervalues())"

Comment: Maybe more efficient to use `d = dict.fromkeys(a, 0)`. Also check the lengths are equal first

Comment: @RobertoLiffredo, In Python, there are cases where an asymptotically poorer solution will out perform an asymptotically better solution, so long as the former can run at C speed while the latter cannot. [E.g., my question on palindromes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580558/why-is-word-word-1-to-test-for-palindrome-faster-than-a-more-algorithmi).

Comment: It all depends on the input size, because using native code will speed up by a constant factor, while a better asymptotic complexity will outperform it. That said, you are absolutely right that in many real-life scenarios you don't have such big datasets.

Comment: Well, this can be more efficient if we add break if we found neg values in array. 

`for x in b:
        d[x] -= 1
        if d[x] < 0 break
`

Answer (score 18):

"but the first one is slower when (for example) the first char of a is nowhere in b".

This kind of degenerate-case performance analysis is not a good idea.  It's a rat-hole of lost time thinking up all kinds of obscure special cases.

Only do the **O**-style "overall" analysis.

Overall, the sorts are **O**( *n* log( *n* ) ).

The `a.count(char) for char in a` solution is **O**( *n* <sup>2</sup> ).  Each count pass is a full examination of the string.

If some obscure special case happens to be faster -- or slower, that's possibly interesting.  But it only matters when you know the frequency of your obscure special cases.  When analyzing sort algorithms, it's important to note that a fair number of sorts involve data that's already in the proper order (either by luck or by a clever design), so sort performance on pre-sorted data matters.

In your obscure special case ("the first char of a is nowhere in b") is this frequent enough to matter?  If it's just a special case you thought of, set it aside.  If it's a fact about your data, then consider it.

Comment: Note that the first one is actually *incorrect* when b contains characters not in a (see Nick's answer). Thinking of all possible "degenerate" and "obscure special cases" is important for correctness. :)

Comment: @ShreegatsaR: Correctness is unrelated to performance.  I'm not addressing correctness in saying that obscure special cases don't matter.  I'm specifically addressing performance and only performance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can make the counting of characters O(n) by doing some bucket counting with an array of size 26. Then you can probably do the inverse for string b and return true iff each of the 26 indices in the array is 0. Totally O(n) where n is len(a) + len(b), or len(a) + len(b) + 26 ops.

Answer (score 7):

I think the first one is the "obvious" way.  It is shorter, clearer, and likely to be faster in many cases because Python's built-in sort is highly optimized.

Comment: But complexity is more important for large strings.

Answer (score 6):

Your second example won't actually work:

```
all(a.count(char) == b.count(char) for char in a)
```

will only work if b does not contain extra characters not in a. It also does duplicate work if the characters in string a repeat.

If you want to know whether two strings are permutations of the same *unique* characters, just do:

```
set(a) == set(b)
```

To correct your second example:

```
all(str1.count(char) == str2.count(char) for char in set(a) | set(b))
```

set() objects overload the bitwise OR operator so that it will evaluate to the union of both sets. This will make sure that you will loop over all the characters of both strings once for each character only.

That said, the sorted() method is much simpler and more intuitive, and would be what I would use.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize you could do the operator overloading, but now I see in the docs there are a bunch of overloaded operators too.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some timed executions on very small strings, using two different methods:
1. sorting
2. counting (specifically the original method by @namin).

```
a, b, c = 'confused', 'unfocused', 'foncused'

sort_method = lambda x,y: sorted(x) == sorted(y)

def count_method(a, b):
    d = {}
    for x in a:
        d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + 1
    for x in b:
        d[x] = d.get(x, 0) - 1
    for v in d.itervalues():
        if v != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Average run times of the 2 methods over 100,000 loops are:

non-match (string a and b)

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import temp' 'temp.sort_method(temp.a, temp.b)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.72 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import temp' 'temp.count_method(temp.a, temp.b)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.1 usec per loop
```

match (string a and c)

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import temp' 'temp.sort_method(temp.a, temp.c)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.47 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import temp' 'temp.count_method(temp.a, temp.c)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 24.6 usec per loop
```

Keep in mind that the strings used are very small. The time complexity of the methods are different, so you'll see different results with very large strings. Choose according to your data, you may even use a combination of the two.

Comment: The set method will return true for "aa" and "a" where the other methods will not. This is probably the best solution if this is the desired behavior, the sorted solution is probably the best one if it is not.

Comment: @Robert: its not set() alone its "set() and len()", so "aa" and "a" will return False in the first method.

Comment: @Norman: agreed. But still I will leave the answer for comparing the rest of the two methods.

Comment: @Norman: removed the set_n_len method and left the comparison of the other two in place. Marked as community wiki

Answer (score 2):

Sorry that my code is not in Python, I have never used it, but I am sure this can be easily translated into python. I believe this is faster than all the other examples already posted. It is also O(n), but stops as soon as possible:

```
public boolean isPermutation(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() != b.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    int[] charCount = new int[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
        ++charCount[a.charAt(i)];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); ++i) {
        if (--charCount[b.charAt(i)] < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

First I don't use a dictionary but an array of size 256 for all the characters. Accessing the index should be much faster. Then when the second string is iterated, I immediately return false when the count gets below 0. When the second loop has finished, you can be sure that the strings are a permutation, because the strings have equal length and no character was used more often in b compared to a.

Comment: This is actually slower in Python than sorted(), Namin's, or JF's. (As well as restricted to ASCII.)

The main problem is in Java you can say charCount['a'] and it will automatically cast the char to an integer for you; in Python you have to use a lot of calls to ord() instead.

Comment: oh, I did not know that. In Java this code would probably be the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Here's martinus code in python.  It only works for ascii strings:

```
def is_permutation(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False

    char_count = [0] * 256
    for c in a:
        char_count[ord(c)] += 1

    for c in b:
        char_count[ord(c)] -= 1
        if char_count[ord(c)] < 0:
            return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

I did a pretty thorough comparison in Java with all words in a book I had. The counting method beats the sorting method in every way. The results:

```
Testing against 9227 words.

Permutation testing by sorting ... done.        18.582 s
Permutation testing by counting ... done.       14.949 s
```

If anyone wants the algorithm and test data set, comment away.

Comment: Please do add the algorithm and test data. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, for solving such problems, e.g. whether String 1 and String 2 are exactly the same or not, easily, you can use an "if" since it is O(1).
Second, it is important to consider that whether they are only numerical values or they can be also words in the string. If the latter one is true (words and numerical values are in the string at the same time), your first solution will not work. You can enhance it by using "ord()" function to make it ASCII numerical value. However, in the end, you are using sort; therefore, in the worst case your time complexity will be O(NlogN). This time complexity is not bad. But, you can do better. You can make it O(N).
My "suggestion" is using Array(list) and set at the same time. Note that finding a value in Array needs iteration so it's time complexity is O(N), but searching a value in set (which I guess it is implemented with HashTable in Python, I'm not sure) has O(1) time complexity:

```
def Permutation2(Str1, Str2):

ArrStr1 = list(Str1) #convert Str1 to array
SetStr2 = set(Str2) #convert Str2 to set

ArrExtra = []

if len(Str1) != len(Str2): #check their length
    return False

elif Str1 == Str2: #check their values
    return True

for x in xrange(len(ArrStr1)):
    ArrExtra.append(ArrStr1[x])

for x in xrange(len(ArrExtra)): #of course len(ArrExtra) == len(ArrStr1) ==len(ArrStr2)
    if ArrExtra[x] in SetStr2: #checking in set is O(1)
        continue
    else:
        return False

return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Go with the first one - it's much more straightforward and easier to understand.  If you're actually dealing with incredibly large strings and performance is a real issue, then don't use Python, use something like C.

As far as the Zen of Python is concerned, that there should only be one obvious way to do things refers to small, simple things.  Obviously for any sufficiently complicated task, there will always be zillions of small variations on ways to do it.

Comment: The sorted function is written in optimized C so performance shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.1/2.7 you can just use `collections.Counter(a) == collections.Counter(b)`.

But `sorted(a) == sorted(b)` is still the most obvious IMHO.  You are talking about permutations - changing order - so sorting is the obvious operation to erase that difference.

Comment: That builds two dicts; Namin's method uses only one.

Comment: @John Machin: true, but unless it's unicode, the dicts are no bigger then 256 entries, so who cares?  Since the counting loop is done in C, it's likely to be faster [not tested].

Comment: collections.Counter looks simpler but it performs a lot worse than the "sorted" method, at least from what I'm seeing on Python 3.1 on Windows, with relatively short strings

Comment: @RicardoReyes I haven't done any measurements, but it's possible that situation might have changed since [Python 3.3 is much better performance-wise than any previous 3.x release](https://www.dropbox.com/s/83ppa5iykqmr14z/Py2v3Hackers2013.pptx) according to Guido.

Comment: @RicardoReyes I think you'll only notice a difference when the strings are very large. The sorting solution is O(n log n) while the dictionary solution is O(n), no?

Answer (score 1):

This is derived from [@patros' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/396570/72321).

```
from collections import Counter

def is_anagram(a, b, threshold=1000000):
    """Returns true if one sequence is a permutation of the other.

    Ignores whitespace and character case.
    Compares sorted sequences if the length is below the threshold,
    otherwise compares dictionaries that contain the frequency of the
    elements.
    """
    a, b = a.strip().lower(), b.strip().lower()
    length_a, length_b = len(a), len(b)
    if length_a != length_b:
        return False
    if length_a < threshold:
        return sorted(a) == sorted(b)
    return Counter(a) == Counter(b)  # Or use @namin's method if you don't want to create two dictionaries and don't mind the extra typing.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an `O(n)` solution in Python using hashing with dictionaries. Notice that I don't use default dictionaries because the code can stop this way if we determine the two strings are not permutations after checking the second letter for instance.

```
def if_two_words_are_permutations(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False
    dic = {}
for ch in s1:
    if ch in dic.keys():
        dic[ch] += 1
    else:
        dic[ch] = 1
for ch in s2:
    if not ch in dic.keys():
        return False
    elif dic[ch] == 0:
        return False
    else:
        dic[ch] -= 1
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a PHP function I wrote about a week ago which checks if two words are anagrams. How would this compare (if implemented the same in python) to the other methods suggested? Comments?

```
public function is_anagram($word1, $word2) {
    $letters1 = str_split($word1);
    $letters2 = str_split($word2);
    if (count($letters1) == count($letters2)) {
        foreach ($letters1 as $letter) {
            $index = array_search($letter, $letters2);
            if ($index !== false) {
                unset($letters2[$index]);
            }
            else { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;        
}
```

---

Here's a *literal* translation to Python of the PHP version (by JFS):

```
def is_anagram(word1, word2):
    letters2 = list(word2)
    if len(word1) == len(word2):
       for letter in word1:
           try:
               del letters2[letters2.index(letter)]
           except ValueError:
               return False               
       return True
    return False
```

Comments:

```
    1. The algorithm is O(N**2). Compare it to @namin's version (it is O(N)).
    2. The multiple returns in the function look horrible.
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't like the multiple returns either. For what I had in mind I wanted a quick escape if false and didn't really know how to refactor that part.

Comment: `del letters2[letters2.index(letter)]` should be written as `letters2.remove(letter)`

Answer (score 0):

This version is faster than any examples presented so far except it is 20% slower than `sorted(x) == sorted(y)` for short strings. It depends on use cases but generally 20% performance gain is insufficient to justify a complication of the code by using different version for short and long strings (as in @patros's answer).

It doesn't use `len` so it accepts any iterable therefore it works even for data that do not fit in memory e.g., given two big text files with many repeated lines it answers whether the files have the same lines (lines can be in any order).

```
def isanagram(iterable1, iterable2):
    d = {}
    get = d.get
    for c in iterable1:
        d[c] = get(c, 0) + 1
    try:
        for c in iterable2:
            d[c] -= 1
        return not any(d.itervalues())
    except KeyError:
        return False
```

It is unclear why this version is faster then `defaultdict` (@namin's) one for large `iterable1` (tested on 25MB thesaurus).

If we replace `get` in the loop by `try: ... except KeyError` then it performs 2 times slower for short strings i.e. when there are few duplicates.

Comment: I think it's because if we find a letter in B that is not in A, yours returns False early whereas Namin's always examines all of both iterables.

Comment: @Kiv: I've checked it when both A and B has the same letters (but maybe different number of them; in this case KeyError never raises) and still the variant with an ordinary dictionary is faster than defauldict' one.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift (or another languages implementation), you could look at the encoded values ( in this case Unicode) and see if they match.

Something like:

```
let string1EncodedValues = "Hello".unicodeScalars.map() {
//each encoded value
$0
//Now add the values
}.reduce(0){ total, value in
    total + value.value
}

let string2EncodedValues = "oellH".unicodeScalars.map() {
    $0
    }.reduce(0) { total, value in
    total + value.value
}

let equalStrings = string1EncodedValues == string2EncodedValues ? true : false
```

You will need to handle spaces and cases as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def matchPermutation(s1, s2):
  a = []
  b = []

  if len(s1) != len(s2):
    print 'length should be the same'
  return

  for i in range(len(s1)):
    a.append(s1[i])

  for i in range(len(s2)):
    b.append(s2[i])

  if set(a) == set(b):
    print 'Permutation of each other'
  else:
    print 'Not a permutation of each other'
  return

#matchPermutaion('rav', 'var') #returns True
matchPermutaion('rav', 'abc') #returns False
```

Answer (score 0):

## Checking if two strings are permutations of each other in Python

```
# First method
def permutation(s1,s2):
 if len(s1) != len(s2):return False;
 return ' '.join(sorted(s1)) == ' '.join(sorted(s2))


# second method
def permutation1(s1,s2):
 if len(s1) != len(s2):return False;
 array = [0]*128;
 for c in s1:
 array[ord(c)] +=1
 for c in s2:
   array[ord(c)] -=1
   if (array[ord(c)]) < 0:
     return False
 return True
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. Pretty straight-forward and readable. This is for strings since the as per the OP.

**Given that the complexity of sorted() is O(n log n).**

```
def checkPermutation(a,b):
    # input: strings a and b
    # return: boolean true if a is Permutation of b

    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    else:
        s_a = ''.join(sorted(a))
        s_b = ''.join(sorted(b))
        if s_a == s_b:
            return True
        else:
            return False

# test inputs
a = 'sRF7w0qbGp4fdgEyNlscUFyouETaPHAiQ2WIxzohiafEGJLw03N8ALvqMw6reLN1kHRjDeDausQBEuIWkIBfqUtsaZcPGoqAIkLlugTxjxLhkRvq5d6i55l4oBH1QoaMXHIZC5nA0K5KPBD9uIwa789sP0ZKV4X6'
b = 'Vq3EeiLGfsAOH2PW6skMN8mEmUAtUKRDIY1kow9t1vIEhe81318wSMICGwf7Rv2qrLrpbeh8bh4hlRLZXDSMyZJYWfejLND4u9EhnNI51DXcQKrceKl9arWqOl7sWIw3EBkeu7Fw4TmyfYwPqCf6oUR0UIdsAVNwbyyiajtQHKh2EKLM1KlY6NdvQTTA7JKn6bLInhFvwZ4yKKbzkgGhF3Oogtnmzl29fW6Q2p0GPuFoueZ74aqlveGTYc0zcXUJkMzltzohoRdMUKP4r5XhbsGBED8ReDbL3ouPhsFchERvvNuaIWLUCY4gl8OW06SMuvceZrCg7EkSFxxprYurHz7VQ2muxzQHj7RG2k3khxbz2ZAhWIlBBtPtg4oXIQ7cbcwgmBXaTXSBgBe3Y8ywYBjinjEjRJjVAiZkWoPrt8JtZv249XiN0MTVYj0ZW6zmcvjZtRn32U3KLMOdjLnRFUP2I3HJtp99uVlM9ghIpae0EfC0v2g78LkZE1YAKsuqCiiy7DVOhyAZUbOrRwXOEDHxUyXwCmo1zfVkPVhwysx8HhH7Iy0yHAMr0Tb97BqcpmmyBsrSgsV1aT3sjY0ctDLibrxbRXBAOexncqB4BBKWJoWkQwUZkFfPXemZkWYmE72w5CFlI6kuwBQp27dCDZ39kRG7Txs1MbsUnRnNHBy1hSOZvTQRYZPX0VmU8SVGUqzwm1ECBHZakQK4RUquk3txKCqbDfbrNmnsEcjFaiMFWkY3Esg6p3Mm41KWysTpzN6287iXjgGSBw6CBv0hH635WiZ0u47IpUD5mY9rkraDDl5sDgd3f586EWJdKAaou3jR7eYU7YuJT3RQVRI0MuS0ec0xYID3WTUI0ckImz2ck7lrtfnkewzRMZSE2ANBkEmg2XAmwrCv0gy4ExW5DayGRXoqUv06ZLGCcBEiaF0fRMlinhElZTVrGPqqhT03WSq4P97JbXA90zUxiHCnsPjuRTthYl7ZaiVZwNt3RtYT4Ff1VQ5KXRwRzdzkRMsubBX7YEhhtl0ZGVlYiP4N4t00Jr7fB4687eabUqK6jcUVpXEpTvKDbj0JLcLYsneM9fsievUz193f6aMQ5o5fm4Ilx3TUZiX4AUsoyd8CD2SK3NkiLuR255BDIA0Zbgnj2XLyQPiJ1T4fjStpjxKOTzsQsZxpThY9Fvjvoxcs3HAiXjLtZ0TSOX6n4ZLjV3TdJMc4PonwqIb3lAndlTMnuzEPof2dXnpexoVm5c37XQ7fBkoMBJ4ydnW25XKYJbkrueRDSwtJGHjY37dob4jPg0axM5uWbqGocXQ4DyiVm5GhvuYX32RQaOtXXXw8cWK6JcSUnlP1gGLMNZEGeDXOuGWiy4AJ7SH93ZQ4iPgoxdfCuW0qbsLKT2HopcY9dtBIRzr91wnES9lDL49tpuW77LSt5dGA0YLSeWAaZt9bDrduE0gDZQ2yX4SDvAOn4PMcbFRfTqzdZXONmO7ruBHHb1tVFlBFNc4xkoetDO2s7mpiVG6YR4EYMFIG1hBPh7Evhttb34AQzqImSQm1gyL3O7n3p98Kqb9qqIPbN1kuhtW5mIbIioWW2n7MHY7E5mt0'

print(checkPermutation(a, b)) #optional
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def permute(str1,str2):
    if sorted(str1) == sorted(str2):
        return True
    else:
        return False

str1="hello"
str2='olehl'
a=permute(str1,str2)
print(a
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def permutation(s1,s2):
    h = defaultdict(int)
    for ch in s1:
        h[ch]+=1
    for ch in s2:
        h[ch]-=1
    for key in h.keys():
        if h[key]!=0 or len(s1)!= len(s2):
            return False
        return True
print(permutation("tictac","tactic"))
```