# Comparing between two words (Anagrams) in Python 2.72

Tags: python, string, compare, anagram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if two strings are permutations of each other in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396421/checking-if-two-strings-are-permutations-of-each-other-in-python)

I need to write a function which receives two words (strings), and checks
if the two words have exactly the same letters, with exactly the same number of appearances for each letter (if so, they are Anagrams). 
The function will return True or False

For example, academics, and academies are *not* Anagrams.

Though they have the same amount of letters, and each word contains the other's letters,
academics contains the letter C once, and the letter E twice.

The word academies contain the letter C twice, and E once, so they are NOT Anagrams.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
def isAnagram( w1, w2):
    return Counter(w1) == Counter(w2)
```

Comment: Doing someone else's homework does not seem like a brilliant idea to me.

Comment: Plus, you didn't even give the nicest solution. Counter requires some form of hashing and counting. I can do better, without any import.

Comment: alright folks, you're right. but i still want to do it on my own.
i thought about creating two dictionaries, putting each letter as a key, and it's appearances counter as the value.
my question is - how do i compare between the two dics ?

Comment: @Anonymouse The point of importing was to show a solution without doing the homework, as imports are usually forbidden. And it worked - @Orr: You can compare the dicts with `==` too.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you just learned, and this should make your homework a lot easier.

Let me guess, you just learned about sorting?

Comment: actually no. nothing about sorting.
just strings, lists and dictionaries