# How many common English words of 4 letters or more can you make from the letters of a given word (each letter can only be used once)

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, puzzle

On the back of a block calendar I found the following riddle:

> How many common English words of 4 letters or more can you make from the letters
>   of the word 'textbook' (each letter can only be used once).

My first solution that I came up with was:

```
from itertools import permutations

with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    words = f.readlines()

words = map(lambda x: x.strip(), words)

given_word = 'textbook'

found_words = []

ps = (permutations(given_word, i) for i in range(4, len(given_word)+1))

for p in ps:
    for word in map(''.join, p):
        if word in words and word != given_word:
            found_words.append(word)
print set(found_words)
```

This gives the result `set(['tote', 'oboe', 'text', 'boot', 'took', 'toot', 'book', 'toke', 'betook'])` but took more than 7 minutes on my machine.

My next iteration was:

```
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    words = f.readlines()

words = map(lambda x: x.strip(), words)

given_word = 'textbook'

print [word for word in words if len(word) >= 4 and sorted(filter(lambda letter: letter in word, given_word)) == sorted(word) and word != given_word]
```

Which return an answer almost immediately but gave as answer: `['book', 'oboe', 'text', 'toot']`

What is the fastest, correct and most pythonic solution to this problem?

(**edit**: added my earlier permutations solution and its different output).

Comment: deleted my answer before seeing your comment, for the same reason you pointed out. thanks

Comment: You can solve that extremely efficient with some pre processing of the dict and assigning every letter a prime representation. I'll write one solution if I have the time later on.

Comment: @Voo I'll wait with choosing a correct answer until you've submitted your solution. I'm looking forward to it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming puzzles (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I'd share this slightly interesting trick although it takes a good bit more code than the rest and isn't really "pythonic". This will take a good bit more code than the other solutions but should be rather quick if I look at the timing the others need.

We're doing a bit preprocessing to speed up the computations. The basic approach is the following: We assign every letter in the alphabet a prime number. E.g. A = 2, B = 3, and so on. We then compute a hash for every word in the alphabet which is simply the product of the prime representations of every character in the word. We then store every word in a dictionary indexed by the hash.

Now if we want to find out which words are equivalent to say `textbook` we only have to compute the same hash for the word and look it up in our dictionary. Usually (say in C++) we'd have to worry about overflows, but in python it's even simpler than that: Every word in the list with the same index will contain exactly the same characters.

Here's the code with the slightly optimization that in our case we only have to worry about characters also appearing in the given word, which means we can get by with a much smaller prime table than otherwise (the obvious optimization would be to only assign characters that appear in the word a value at all - it was fast enough anyhow so I didn't bother and this way we could pre process only once and do it for several words). The prime algorithm is useful often enough so you should have one yourself anyhow ;)

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations

PRIMES = list(gen_primes(256)) # some arbitrary prime generator

def get_dict(path):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            word = line.strip().upper()
            hash = compute_hash(word)
            res[hash].append(word)
    return res

def compute_hash(word):
    hash = 1
    for char in word:
        try:
            hash *= PRIMES[ord(char) - ord(' ')]
        except IndexError:
            # contains some character out of range - always 0 for our purposes
            return 0
    return hash

def get_result(path, given_word):
    words = get_dict(path)
    given_word = given_word.upper()
    result = set()
    powerset = lambda x: powerset(x[1:]) + [x[:1] + y for y in powerset(x[1:])] if x else [x]
    for word in (word for word in powerset(given_word) if len(word) >= 4):
        hash = compute_hash(word)
        for equiv in words[hash]:
            result.add(equiv)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = "dict.txt"
    given_word = "textbook"
    result = get_result(path, given_word)
    print(result)
```

Runs on my ubuntu word list (98k words) rather quickly, but not what I'd call pythonic since it's basically a port of a c++ algorithm. Useful if you want to compare more than one word that way..

Comment: Very clear explanation and code, thanks. Your code was also returned the correct words `kobe`, `otto` and `toto` and now I am wondering why my permutations solution didn't turn up those.

Comment: @BioGeek You don't handle uppercase/lowercase equivalently.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
from itertools import permutations, chain

with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as fp:
    words = set(fp.read().split())

given_word = 'textbook'

perms = (permutations(given_word, i) for i in range(4, len(given_word)+1))
pwords = (''.join(p) for p in chain(*perms))
matches = words.intersection(pwords)

print matches
```

which gives

```
>>> print matches
set(['textbook', 'keto', 'obex', 'tote', 'oboe', 'text', 'boot', 'toto', 'took', 'koto', 'bott', 'tobe', 'boke', 'toot', 'book', 'bote', 'otto', 'toke', 'toko', 'oket'])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a generator `itertools.permutations` with which you can gather all permutations of a sequence with a specified length. That makes it easier:

```
from itertools import permutations

GIVEN_WORD = 'textbook'

with open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r') as f:
    words = [s.strip() for s in f.readlines()]

print len(filter(lambda x: ''.join(x) in words, permutations(GIVEN_WORD, 4)))
```

Edit #1: Oh! It says "4 or more" ;) Forget what I said!

Edit #2: This is the second version I came up with:

```
LETTERS = set('textbook')

with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    WORDS = filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 4, [l.strip() for l in f])

matching = filter(lambda x: set(x).issubset(LETTERS) and all([x.count(c) == 1 for c in x]), WORDS)
print len(matching)
```

Comment: Haven't dug into this much, but this code gives me different results and takes more than 20X longer to execute.

Comment: Please also note my version caring about every matched word containing every letter only once.

Comment: Your second version only returns words where each letter is different (in this case: `toke`), but `tote`, `oboe`, `text`, `boot`, `took`, `toot`, `book`, and `betook` are also valid solutions.

Comment: Quote: "each letter can only be used once". ;)

Comment: @Gandaro Well but there are two `t`s in textbook and each can be used once ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create the whole power set, then check whether the dictionary word is in the set (order of the letters doesn't matter):

```
powerset = lambda x: powerset(x[1:]) + [x[:1] + y for y in powerset(x[1:])] if x else [x]

pw = map(lambda x: sorted(x), powerset(given_word))
filter(lambda x: sorted(x) in pw, words)
```

Comment: Cool, I hadn't before heard of the concept of a powerset. Small nitpick, your current implementation doesn't filter out the words of lengt 4 or more.

Answer (score 2):

The following just checks each word in the dictionary to see if it is of the appropriate length, and then if it is a permutation of 'textbook'. I borrowed the permutation check from 
[Checking if two strings are permutations of each other in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396421/checking-if-two-strings-are-permutations-of-each-other-in-python)
but changed it slightly.

```
given_word = 'textbook'

with open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r') as f:
    words = [s.strip() for s in f.readlines()]

matches = []
for word in words:
    if word != given_word and 4 <= len(word) <= len(given_word):
        if all(word.count(char) <= given_word.count(char) for char in word):
            matches.append(word)
print sorted(matches)
```

This finishes almost immediately and gives the correct result.

Comment: No lambda, no map, no filter: at last, **this** is Pythonic. Though using generator comprehensions instead of a list comprehension and an accumulation loop should be more efficient.

Comment: @Evpok I can understand (and agree) why map and filter wouldn't be necessary with list comprehensions, but I don't see why creating dozens of mini functions would be especially pythonic instead of using lambdas?

Comment: See [Guido's answer](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) : “[…] once map(), filter() and reduce() are gone, there aren't a whole lot of places where you really need to write very short local functions […]”. Why would you need lambdas if you use comprehensions?

Comment: @Evpok Not for generators obviously, but for lots of other situations. Passing trivial functions (say comparators) around is often useful (basically any kind of callback) Also currying can be an immensely useful feature in my experience. But certainly depends on the coding style.

Comment: @Voo Agreed for comparators, I actually love functional coding style and I regularly abuse `functools.partial`. But Python was not meant to be a functional language.

Comment: @Evpok: A bit off topic here, but please would you be kind enough to consider this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159414/using-delphi-version-of-hyphenation-algorithm)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Permutations get very big for longer words. Try *counterrevolutionary* for example.

I would filter the dict for words from 4 to len(word) (8 for textbook). 
Then I would filter with regular expression "oboe".matches ("[textbook]+").

The remaining words, I would sort, and compare them with a sorted version of your word, ("beoo", "bekoottx") with jumping to the next index of a matching character, to find mismatching numbers of characters:

```
("beoo", "bekoottx") 
("eoo", "ekoottx") 
("oo", "koottx") 
("oo", "oottx") 
("o", "ottx") 
("", "ttx") => matched


("bbo", "bekoottx") 
("bo", "ekoottx") => mismatch
```

Since I don't talk python, I leave the implementation as an exercise to the audience.