# Why is `word == word[::-1]` to test for palindrome faster than a more algorithmic solution in Python?

Tags: python, performance

I wrote a disaster of a question on Code Review asking why Python programmers normally test if a string is a palindrome by comparing the string to itself reversed, instead of a more algorithmic way with lower complexity, assuming that the normal way would be faster.

Here is the pythonic way:

```
def is_palindrome_pythonic(word):
    # The slice requires N operations, plus memory
    # and the equality requires N operations in the worst case
    return word == word[::-1]
```

Here is my attempt at a more efficient way to accomplish this:

```
def is_palindrome_normal(word):
    # This requires N/2 operations in the worst case
    low = 0
    high = len(word) - 1
    while low < high:
        if word[low] != word[high]:
            return False
        low += 1
        high -= 1
    return True
```

I would expect the normal way would be faster than the pythonic way. See for example [this great article](http://componentsprogramming.com/palindromes/)

Timing it with `timeit`, however, brought exactly the opposite result:

```
setup = '''
def is_palindrome_pythonic(word):
    # ...

def is_palindrome_normal(word):
    # ...

# N here is 2000
first_half = ''.join(map(str, (i for i in range(1000))))
word = first_half + first_half[::-1]
'''

timeit.timeit('is_palindrome_pythonic(word)', setup=setup, number=1000)
# 0.0052

timeit.timeit('is_palindrome_normal(word)', setup=setup, number=1000)
# 0.4268
```

I then figured that my `n` was too small, so I changed the length of word from `2000` to `2,000,000`. The pythonic way took about 16 seconds on average, whereas the normal way ran several minutes before I canceled it.

Incidentally, in the best case scenario, where the very first letter does not match the very last letter, the normal algorithm was much faster.

What explains the extreme difference between the speeds of the two algorithms?

Comment: Well, one of them is two operations (a string reversal and an equality test), the other is... I'm not counting but on the order of probably dozens of operations.

Comment: The pythonic just slices the string, while the other is iterative... many more steps in the latter

Comment: @kindall a string reversal is N/2 operations, and the equality test is N operations in the worst case. The other is N/2 operations in the worst case. [This article](http://componentsprogramming.com/palindromes/) explains it well.

Comment: @AndrewLi a slice and a equality test have more steps than the latter solution.  [This article](http://componentsprogramming.com/palindromes/) explains it well.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen Complexity isn't everything though. You also have to account for operation count.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen How so? Time Complexity isn't everything. Step count is a huge factor in time.

Comment: CPython has no JIT, so avoiding interpreter overhead is a huge part of optimizing Python code. (Also, I'm baffled by how many commenters seem to think string reversal and string equality testing are each "one operation" or "one step".)

Comment: For small data we can treat the execution times of Python instructions as roughly equivalent and simply count the instructions. This is because things like string slicing are implemented in C and are so much faster than Python code that the interpreter overhead overwhelms their timings. Also, for the record, reversing a string natively in Python is O(N) not O(N/2) since strings are immutable.  :-)

Comment: @kindall thanks; I was thinking of how `reversed()` is implemented in Python as opposed to reversing via the slice operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the "Pythonic" way with slicing is implemented in C. The interpreter / VM doesn't need to execute more than approximately once.  The bulk of the algorithm is spent in a tight loop of native code.

Comment: As a side thought, when one is doing an interview in Python, should he stick to the pythonic algorithms, or should he perform the normal algorithm while noting to the interviewer "of course this could be done faster in python while doing xyz, but for the purposes of this interview I will implement the algorithm as it usually would in java" ?

Answer (score 3):

As much as I love Python, I have to say that if you want maximum speed you probably shouldn't be using Python. ;)

The rule of thumb in Python time optimization is to use operators or module functions that do the bulk of the work at C speed rather than equivalent code running at Python speed. Even if the two equivalent approaches are using algorithms with the same big-O complexity, the time scaling factor of (mostly) running directly on the CPU vs running on the Python virtual machine has a *big* impact.

This is even true of an algorithm that's mostly just integer arithmetic, since Python integers are immutable objects, so when you do arithmetic there's the overhead of allocating and initialising a new integer object and disposing of the old one. CPython tries to be frugal, and is pretty smart at managing memory (so every new object doesn't require a system call to allocate memory), and of course the CPython interpreter maintains a cache of integers from -5 to 256 (inclusive) so that arithmetic with small numbers isn't so bad. But it's certainly slower than doing arithmetic at C speed with machine integers.

You can see the difference even with a simple counting loop. On my admittedly ancient 32 bit machine running Python 3.6, using the Bash `time` command to do the timings,

```
m = 5000000
for i in range(m): 
    i
```

is roughly twice as fast as

```
m = 5000000
i = 0
while i<m:
    i += 1
```

because `range` can do the arithmetic at C speed, even though it still has to create a new integer object on each iteration. If you replace the `i` line in the `range` version with `pass` the time is roughly halved.

With more complicated algorithms the time differences can be much more significant, eg string or list copying that happens at the C level can often be done with efficient CPU operators that are much faster than chugging along on the Python virtual machine with Python code.

I agree that this can take a while to get used to if you come from a language that gets compiled to native machine code. And I admit that even after over 10 years of using Python it still feels a little weird to me that when (for example) you need to do some bit manipulation stuff that it can often be faster in Python to do it using string operations on a string composed of '0's and '1's that to do it using the traditional bitwise and arithmetic integer operators.

OTOH, I think it's useful to know the traditional algorithms as well as the Pythonic ones. It's rare that a programmer will work *only* in Python, so it's good to know how to do things in languages that don't work the way that Python does.